# Android Cursor initialization

Tags: android, sqlite

I have designed a database. Here is my code:

```
  Cursor cursor =database.query(ColumnID.AGENT_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            County county = new County();
            county.setId(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.ID)));
            county.setAgent_Name(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.AGENT_NAME)));
            county.setAddress_Line_1(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.ADDRESS_LINE_1)));


            countyList.add(county);
        }
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

Reference: [Android Cursor initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37050574/android-cursor-initialization)

Comment: There's [quite a lot of similar questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Make+sure+the+Cursor+is+initialized+correctly+before+accessing+data+from+it).

Comment: Please post your full code @Raseem Ayatt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're getting the error because there are no records in the datatable and you're trying to moveToNext() on an empty set, or if it is because you are accessing the query for results that aren't there.

If its the former: The error seems to be because there are no records in the cursor, when you try to moveToNext() the record doesn't exist. Its the SQLite version of a null pointer exception (sort of).

Instead, try:

```
Cursor cursor =database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + ColumnID.AGENT_TABLE);

cursor.moveToFirst();
//this checks to make sure you don't have an empty set
if(!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
    do{
        County county = new County();
        county.setId(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.ID)));
        county.setAgent_Name(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.AGENT_NAME)));
        county.setAddress_Line_1(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.ADDRESS_LINE_1)));


        countyList.add(county);
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
} else{
    Log.v("MyTag", "There are no countries in the data set");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor =database.query(ColumnID.AGENT_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);

if (cursor.getCount() > 0) 
{ 
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
    {
        County county = new County();
        county.setId(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.ID)));
        county.setAgent_Name(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.AGENT_NAME)));
        county.setAddress_Line_1(cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ColumnID.ADDRESS_LINE_1)));

        countyList.add(county);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why check the row count? You can do `if(cursor.moveToFirst())`...

Comment: Still im getting error

Comment: im not checking row count and i'm adding table values into arraylist

Comment: try my updated answer or post your logcat..

Comment: inside while condition??

Comment: getting same error

Comment: please post your logcat..i'm not able to solve your issue without knowing actual problem..